# Fetching data from a Array of Objects in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Project Array Values

A collection students contains the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 70, 87, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 90, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 79, 85, 80 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 95, 90, 96 ] }
```

In the following query, the projection { "grades.$": 1 } returns only the first element greater than or equal to 85 for the grades field.

```
db.students.find( { semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } }, { "grades.$": 1 } )
```

The operation returns the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 87 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "grades" : [ 85 ] }
```

**But in the following result I need "semester" values as well. And also if it has multiple values at the same position as semester.**

**Edit**: Multiple Values at same position like if the collections is as follows:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "subject": "Maths", "class": "5", "division" : "A" "grades" : [ 70, 87, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "semester" : 1, "subject": "Maths", "class": "5", "division" : "A" "grades" : [ 90, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "semester" : 1, "subject": "Maths", "class": "5", "division" : "A" "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "semester" : 2, "subject": "Maths", "class": "5", "division" : "A" "grades" : [ 79, 85, 80 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "semester" : 2, "subject": "Maths", "class": "5", "division" : "A" "grades" : [ 88, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "semester" : 2, "subject": "Maths", "class": "5", "division" : "A" "grades" : [ 95, 90, 96 ] }
```

i.e. Collection contains multiple fields like "subject", "class", "division" at the same position in as the "semester"

Comment: you need it add it in project section like `db.students.find( { semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } }, { "grades.$": 1 , "semester":1} )`

Comment: `And also if it has multiple values at the same position as semester` what do you mean by this line, can you explain?

Comment: @Shrabanee - Explained in edits

Comment: So you should look into https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-specific-fields-in-embedded-documents

Comment: Can you add the expected json response to the post ?

Comment: the query projection will only return the first matching value from an array. if you want multiple array elements returned (like all matching values) you will need to use aggregate with $project and $filter.

Comment: by the way, your array has simple values in it, not objects like your title states.